# IntelliJ: Interactive questions turned off: cant authenticate to svn

Tags: svn, authentication, version-control, intellij-idea, dialog

My IntelliJ won't give me the authentication dialog because it says

Interactive questions turned off: see flag --force-interactive

What is this crap? Where should I give this flag and why can't I edit it in
the settings?

:-(